# Loaded Ubuntu 13.10 on Mac

Tags: grub2, 13.10, system-installation

I've installed Ubuntu 13.10 both on a seperate partition and alongside osx on my mac and whenever I have to restart at the end of the installation, it get:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.00-19ubuntu2.1

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

What now?!

Answer (score 0):

Boot back into your live cd and run boot-repair ([instructions here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)) to update your grub EFI.  Provided the installation did not fail this should get your mac booting into ubuntu.